# Laravel Sanctum accepting requests even though XSRF-cookie isn't set

Tags: php, laravel

I've just created a new repository, downloaded sanctum, migrated, and changed nothing but `routes/api.php`. Then, I tried to register a user. It accepted it without first calling `/sanctum/csrf-cookie`. What happened I'm confused

Comment: can you see a new entry in the database table personal access token?

Comment: Yes, in the personal_access_tokens table

Comment: that mean sanctum is working ok, you are using the 'mobile' sanctum implementation, the ```/sanctum/csrf-cookie``` is for spa apps with session, you can see it in the docs

Comment: So you're telling me sending calling `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` isnt required? if it isn't, why  does the middleware contains `config('sanctum.middleware.verify_csrf_token', VerifyCsrfToken::class),`  ?

Comment: that middleware is applied to spa apps (with session) as i said before. if you are building a mobile app (or a spa app without session) that is not applied. so no the call to ```/sanctum...``` is not required

Comment: Understand, appreciate it!